# UUENCODE data in the iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, uuencode

Is there any way to uuencode data in the iPhone SDK? An API call or perhaps a library?

Comment: what type of data are you talking about?? You need to clarify this question

Comment: binary data, nothing specific, NSData objects.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you need to be able to uuencode data from an iPhone app?

Comment: So I can email it or post it to a server that only accepts text input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a built-in API to uuencode data, no, but the algorithm is pretty straightforward (the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuencoding) gives a good overview), and there's plenty of C source code out in the world (here's [one example](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~burkardt/c_src/uuencode/uuencode.html) that looks like it's freely available/reusable). Since uuencode operates at the level of bytes, C code should be fine... you can get bytes from an **NSData** directly, or with **NSString** methods like `UTF8String` and `cStringUsingEncoding`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to convert binary data so you can submit it to a web-site you may want to consider using [Base64](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html) (also [here](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?BaseSixtyFour)) instead.